# Jquery div text change not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to write a password strength function. When a user types in a password it shows them whether their password is "weak","good", or "strong" using a meter and text.

However if a user typed a weak password and deleted their password in the input field then proceeds to type a strong password the meter will show as strong however the text stays as "weak" since that is the last password they typed before erasing their text. Here is my query. I have tried both .text and .html but they both give me the same results

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a link to the code. It works on JFiddle but it doesn't work on my website!

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/sdcy3ydL/)

```
Code in JFiddle link
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code. I think you forgot to add

`$('#password-warning').text("")` in the last `else if`.

By the way, instead of using `===` why don't you just use `==`. Don't forget `===` requires both operand to be of the same type. Try to replace your last `else if` block with the following :

```
else if (password == ""){
    $('#password-strength-meter').val(0);
    $('#password-warning').text("");
}
```

Comment: You welcome. Go though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons to undertand the difference between === and ==